# Entropy of convex combination of dirac points are positive

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Let $X$ be a compact metric space. $T:X \to X$ be a homeomorphism. Assume that the measure$\mu=\lambda \delta_{a}+(1-\lambda)\delta_{b},$ where $\delta$ is the Dirac measure and $0<\lambda<1.$ Is it turn that the measure theoretical entropy $h_{\mu}(T)>0?$

Comment: Could you define what you call $h_\mu$?

Comment: @LL3.14 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure-preserving_dynamical_system